# How to add minutes to military time?

Tags: python, time, addition

Following is the code which outputs current time, let say `22:59`. How do I add the value of `t` to the current time if `t` is in hours, and display it as military time on the screen?

```
import datetime

currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(currentTime,'%H:%M'))

v = 50
s = 131
t = s/v
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking. Are you saying you want to add a certain number of hours to currentTime and then convert it to military time? So two separate operations?

Comment: i want to add the value of t to current time

Answer (score 1):

Use `timedelta` and avoid loading whole packages.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

currentTime = datetime.now()
t = 131/50

print(datetime.strftime(currentTime+timedelta(hours=t),'%H:%M'))
```

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. The answer works well I just need to ask you one little thing is 131/50 = 2.62 which means it is 3 hours 2 minutes but and when I am trying to add t the current time it is not giving right answer please comment.